# How do I include `kable_classic_2()` properly in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, kable, kableextra

According to the `kableExtra` documentation, this code should output the table correctly,

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("mtcars"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("mpg", "mpg Limit",
                     min = 11, max = 33, value = 20)
      ),

      mainPanel(
         tableOutput("mtcars_kable")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  library(dplyr)
  library(kableExtra)
   output$mtcars_kable <- function() {
     req(input$mpg)
     mtcars %>%
       mutate(car = rownames(.)) %>%
       select(car, everything()) %>%
       filter(mpg <= input$mpg) %>%
       knitr::kable("html") %>%
       kable_classic_2() %>% 
       add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 5, "Group 2" = 6))
   }
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, the Output does not correspond to the table theme `kable_classic_2()`. So I changed the `output$mtcars_kable` such that it prints the `HTML`-codes directly instead, in the following,

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("mtcars"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("mpg", "mpg Limit",
                        min = 11, max = 33, value = 20)
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            uiOutput("mtcars_kable")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    library(dplyr)
    library(kableExtra)
    output$mtcars_kable <- renderUI(
        
        {
            req(input$mpg)
            mtcars %>%
                mutate(car = rownames(.)) %>%
                select(car, everything()) %>%
                filter(mpg <= input$mpg) %>%
                knitr::kable("html") %>%
                kable_classic_2() %>% 
                add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 5, "Group 2" = 7))
        }
    )
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, this only outputs the `HTML`-codes rather than rendering them into an actual table. My desired output is that which is found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#HTML_Only_Features) under alternative themes.

Answer (score 3):

#### It seems shiny doesn't take kableExtra css ?

You mention doc from here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/use_kable_in_shiny.html

`tableOutput` in UI, and a simple `function()` in server which return the result filtered.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("mtcars"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("mpg", "mpg Limit",
                  min = 11, max = 33, value = 20)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("mtcars_kable")
    )
  )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {
  library(dplyr)
  library(kableExtra)
  output$mtcars_kable <- function()(
    
    {
      req(input$mpg)
      mtcars %>%
        mutate(car = rownames(.)) %>%
        select(car, everything()) %>%
        filter(mpg <= input$mpg) %>%
        knitr::kable("html") %>%
        kable_classic_2() %>% 
        add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 5, "Group 2" = 7))
    }
  )
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: shiny example]

Maybe better to build car column like this:

```
    mtcars %>%
      as_tibble(rownames = "car") %>% 
      select(car, everything()) %>%
```

to have a tibble without row names.

So, like you note in the comments, css styling from kableExtra is not rendered at all. (I have tested updating all packages to see if something change, but no).

### other solution with gt package

Another option then is to migrate to gt package where you can edit completely the css... The result is pretty clean but obviously it's not a kableExtra solution to your question.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("mtcars"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("mpg", "mpg Limit",
                  min = 11, max = 33, value = 20)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
       gt::gt_output("mtcars_kable")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  library(dplyr)
  library(kableExtra)
  output$mtcars_kable <- gt::render_gt({
    req(input$mpg)
    mtcars %>%
      as_tibble(rownames = "car") %>% 
      select(car, everything()) %>%
      filter(mpg <= input$mpg) %>%
      gt::gt(id = "cars") %>% 
      gt::tab_spanner(
        label = "Group 1",
        columns = 2:6) %>% 
      gt::tab_spanner(
        label = "Group 2",
        columns = 6:12) %>% 
      gt::opt_css(
        css = "
    #cars .gt_table {
      background-color: #fffggg;
    }
    #cars .gt_row {
      padding: 4px 12px;
    }
    #cars .gt_col_heading {
      text-align: center !important;
    }
    ")
  })
}
```

[image: with GT]

Comment: Thank you for your input. Did you run my code? I get the exact same output as you; however it is not consistent with the actual expected output.

Comment: ok, with your first code I get "Error in htmlTable_add_header_above: The new header row you provided has a different total number of columns with the original kable output." What do you exactly expect ? Sorry, I may not have undertood the point

Comment: Ok I see the point now. Sorry.. It's probably a css problem, I have it too. Testing another kableExtra style gives the same "basic" table as a result...

Comment: Dont worry about it. A work-around is rendering the table via markdown and then re-load it in Shiny. But thats like scratching your ear with a strangers foot :-)

Comment: finally, for my own knowledge, I edited my answer with another code by gt package, if it's useful for someone else. And I have not found an Issue about that precisely on kableExtra github.

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you! Allow me to play around with it this evening and see how it works. Would it make sense to open an issue on Github on this matter?